# Edittext in AlertDialog as global variable

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-alertdialog

I have an AlertDialog with a EditText inside it written in this way:

```
final EditText input = new EditText(this);
alert.setView(input);
```

The "problem" is that i can't use outside the dialog the variable `input` of this EditText.. I tried declare the variable as `private final EditText input;` as global but it returns some errors. How can i do?

Comment: You dont need to use edittext global. You need to look how to create alertdialogs.

Comment: You can't make it global.

Comment: what do you mean? I need use the the edittext outside the dialog to call the value i wrote inside it

Comment: @End.Game Do you want to use value of EditText through your class?

Comment: And if you make it global then what is the error show ur logcat. It will be Null poniter excetion.

Comment: try saving a copy of input object in a EditText.

Answer (score 0):

This will be useful for you :

[android-prompt-user-input-dialog-example](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-prompt-user-input-dialog-example/)

```
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                // get prompts.xml view
                LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(context);
                View promptsView = li.inflate(R.layout.prompts, null);

                AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                        context);

                // set prompts.xml to alertdialog builder
                alertDialogBuilder.setView(promptsView);

                final EditText userInput = (EditText) promptsView
                        .findViewById(R.id.editTextDialogUserInput);

                // set dialog message
                alertDialogBuilder
                    .setCancelable(false)
                    .setPositiveButton("OK",
                      new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                        // get user input and set it to result
                        // edit text
                        result.setText(userInput.getText());
                        }
                      })
                    .setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                      new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                        }
                      });

                // create alert dialog
                AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

                // show it
                alertDialog.show();

            }
        });
```

Comment: So in this way i can do something like: `private final EditText userInput;` and in the dialog using only: `userInput = (EditText) promptsView
                        .findViewById(R.id.editTextDialogUserInput);`?

Comment: You try to put your edit text into alertdialog before dialog start. You create a gloabal edittext in activity and want to use it in alertdialog. This not a good approach. You should create an edittext inside alertdialog. In this link you will get what i mean. Please try it first.

Comment: to define a global variable, you need to define the value at the position between the oncreate method and the the whole class...something like this:
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {
EditText input;
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        input=new EditText(this); 

then when you want to get the the content of your textview then use
 input.getText().toString();